# AVR: Interrupt build error

Tags: avr, c, interrupts

I am trying to learn how to use interrupts for a project using an Attiny85. I have written a simple program from what I have learned from tutorials. However when I try to build the program in Atmel Studio, I get this error message:

"Error  2   static declaration of '__vector_1' follows non-static declaration"

I do not understand what this means or where my mistake located. I've searched all around for answers but I haven't found the reason for the error yet. Here is my code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>


int main (void)
{

    DDRB = 0b11111011; // set all pins to be output except PB2 to prevent false signals 

    GIMSK |= (1<<INT0); //set PB2 to interrupt
    sei();

    MCUCR |=(1<<ISC00);  //set to detect any change as interrupt
    MCUCR &= ~(1<<ISC01);


    ISR(INT0_vect)

    {

    // dot
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(200);

    // dot
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(200);

    // dot
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(600);

    // dash
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(500);

    // dash
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(500);

    // dash
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(600);

    // dot
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(200);

    // dot
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(200);

    // dot
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(2000);


        }

    while (1) {


    }



    }
```

If anyone could provide assistance it would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

-David

Answer (score 3):

You've written your ISR within `main()`. Don't do that; close the previous function first.

```
void main(void)
{
   ...
}

ISR(...)
{
   ...
}
```